# Is there a way to open multiple chests at once in Game of war?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

I bought a legendary package in game of war: fire age and it gave me 1000 loot chests, the problem is that i can only open them one by one to my knowledge. 
Is it possible to open multiple chests at once or do i have to tap 1000 times to open all of my loot chests?

thank you

Comment: Also see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264744/how-do-i-efficiently-open-chests-in-game-of-war-for-free

Comment: Which has no answer other than "install this software to cheat"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](https://downthescreenhole.com/forums/topic/game-war-finally-releases-open-vip-prestige-level-12/) and others I found, you have to have "2.5 million VIP points" in order to unlock the "Use all" option. What I saw on a different article is acquiring that many VIP Points would require that you spend around $2,900. Oh, mobile games, oh you!

Comment: Actually it only cost me 200$ to get to VIP 13 (which is what you need)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get (or buy) "Use all" items, which allow you to open all or a lot of 1 type of chest at once.

Comment: ?? Question was: how do you open multiple chests at once? Is this not an answer to that question?