# How do I efficiently open chests in Game of War for free?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

How do I efficiently open chests in Game of War for free?  I know I can use the item that opens 500 at once, but those often cost gold.

Answer (score 1):

You can open all chests for free once you reach VIP Prestige 12. You can then open all of 1 specific chest for free. Once you reach VIP prestige 15, you can then open all chests for free!

Answer (score -3):

First, you need an android emulator.  I use bluestacks.  Then install Game of War in your bluestacks image.

Then you need a keyboard macro program that will automatically click for you.  Autohotkey is such a program.  You can let it run for however long you like, and it'll open up the chests for free.  Here's the keyboard macro I use.  You'll need to adjust the X and Y values.  The "5" key starts running the macro, and escape cancels it.

```
Escape::
ExitApp
Return

$5::


loop 200
{
    Send, {Click 776, 374}
    Sleep, 1000
    Send, {Click 735, 275}
    Sleep, 2000
    Send, {Click 798, 235}
    Sleep, 1000

}
```

Comment: There's a better way to open all chests, see my post above for more information.